# Consult ajax - show value cell table

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-table, cell

I want show value of input"name" in my table data.

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="id" class="id">1</input></td>
            <td><input id="name" class="name"></input></td>
        <tr>
    <tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="id" class="id">2</input></td>
            <td><input id="name" class="name"></input></td>
        <tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I use this code to obtain the value but I don't know how I can show it.

```
$('#mytable tbody').each(function() {

    var id = $(this).find(".id").val(); //obtain Id value

    $.ajax({
        url:"search_name.php", //search in database name with this id
        type:"POST",
        data:id,
        dataType:"json",
        success:
            function(return)
            {
                $(this).find(".name").val(return.name); 
            }               
    })

});

})
```

The value of `return.name` is ok, its the name that I want to show but doesn't
 appears in input with class name.

Comment: `this` inside the success function is **not** the element ?

Comment: And IDs must be unique on document context... Regarding ajax success callback context, use as $.ajax() option: `context: this,`  And please, `return` is  reserved keyword, use something else

Comment: return and Ids its ok but i dont understand how cn i use context: this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is `this` has different context within the ajax callbacks and is not the element instance you are expecting from your `each` loop

There are several ways to resolve the scope issue for `this`.

The least commonly used approach is there is a `context` option for `$.ajax`

```
$('#mytable tbody').each(function () {
    $.ajax({
        /* other options left out for brevity*/
        context: this, // per docs "object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks"
        success: function (return) {
            /* "this" is now the tbody instance*/
            $(this).find(".name").val(return.name);
        }
    });
});
```

The more common approach is to store a reference to the element prior to calling `$.ajax`

```
$('#mytable tbody').each(function () {
    var $tbody = $(this); // store instance in variable
    $.ajax({
       /* other options */
        success: function (return) {
            $tbody.find(".name").val(return.name); 
        }
    });
});
```

The second approach is perhaps a bit easier to read with regard to scope